# confused between instance variable and local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently started learning ruby and i am confused between instance variable and local variable and class variable. so , i recently written code which will find the largest palindrome in 1000 prime numbers. 
code is:

```
def prime_large(number)
  arr_prime = []
  Prime.each(number) do |x|
    new_arr_prime = arr_prime.push(x.to_s)
    updated = new_arr_prime.select { |y| y.reverse == y }
  end
  p updated.max 
end
p prime_large(1000)
```

error i got is:

```
undefined local variable or method `updated' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I know that updated is a local variable of prime so i can't access it outside it but i changed the code by replacing it with @updated as below:

```
def prime_large(number)
  arr_prime = []
  Prime.each(number) do |x|
    new_arr_prime = arr_prime.push(x.to_s)
    @updated = new_arr_prime.select { |y| y.reverse == y }
  end
  p @updated.max 
end
p prime_large(1000)
```

after changing it , i got the output:

```
"929"
"929"
```

in my code , without creating a class how  my instance variable ( @updated) is working . i am confused between local and instance variable . can anyone please explain me the differences and how they work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example you created a **local** variable `updated`, that is only accessible within the scope of the block it is defined in. Meaning, it is available only within `Prime.each(number) do end` block.

In your second example you created **instance variable** `@updated`.

> without creating a class how my instance variable ( @updated) is
>   working

It is because in Ruby everything occurs in the context of some object. Even though you did not created a class, you are being in the top-level context, in the context of object `main`.

Thus, any instance variables defined within top-level are instance variables of this object `main`.

So going back to your issue, to overcome it you'll want to just define the `updated` local variable outside the `Prime.each(number) do end` block:

```
def prime_large(number)
  arr_prime = []
  updated   = nil # initialize local varialbe
  Prime.each(number) do |x|
    new_arr_prime = arr_prime.push(x.to_s)
    updated = new_arr_prime.select { |y| y.reverse == y } # assign new value
  end
  p updated.max 
end
p prime_large(1000)
```

To test it you can open irb or pry and check it yourself:

```
self               # the object in the context of which you are currently
#=> main
self.class         # main is an instance of class Object, any methods defined
                   # within main are added to Object class as instance methods
#=> Object
instance_variables # list of it's instance variables, none yet created
#=> []
@variable = 1      # create and instance variable
#=> 1
instance_variables # now created variable occurs in the list of current object's instance variables
#=> [:@variable]
def hello; :hello end # define method
#=> :hello
self.class.public_instance_methods(false) # list instance methods defined in Object
#=> [:hello]
```

What you now want to read about is lexical scopes in Ruby.

Comment: It might be useful to explain how to solve the problem (namely: initialize the variable outside of the block scope).

Comment: @Jordan I was going to write about it, but I thought the whole thing about scope makes it intuitive. I'll edit the answer. Thx!